# Installing APK file programatically in android

Tags: android

I am making an android app which allows me to download and install an `.apk` file.

**Problem**

I am able to download the file but not able to install it.

code to install `.apk` is as follows

```
Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            apkFile);

Intent installAPK = new Intent();

installAPK.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

installAPK.setDataAndType(fileURI, apkFile,
                         "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(installAPK);
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here? How can i install the downloaded `.apk` file?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: there's no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Install apk programmatically

```
Uri fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            apkFile);
Intent installAPK = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
installAPK.setData(fileURI);
installAPK.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(installAPK);
```